# What can forensic analysts extract from a fully encrypted phone?

Tags: encryption, android, forensics

I was very disappointed to hear that my friend, who had his Android phone seized not too long ago, has had his phone broken by police forensics.

As far as I know, it was a few years old, Samsung, and had a 20-digit password.

It seems that encryption meant nothing, however, as he has received court documents notifying him that the police used Cellebrite to perform a 'full file disk extraction'.

It seems that the encryption on his fully updated phone has been broken.

Questions:

- With this type of extraction, can forensic analysts get his device password from the dump, in plain text?
- Full file disk encryption means more than just an image of the device, right? Everything should be assumed to be compromised at this point, correct?

Comment: This is a much better question, thank you.

Comment: "it was a few years old" -- the age and version of Android will really matter in an answer. A phone can be "fully updated" and still "out of date". Can you provide details on the Android version?

Comment: There are some recent articles about Cellebrite. Have you looked this kind of thing up? https://tech.hindustantimes.com/tech/news/android-phones-are-harder-to-crack-than-iphones-according-to-a-forensic-detective-story-zdnaQkVWTuZTudqECMEMXK.html and https://www.phonearena.com/news/android-is-now-harder-to-crack-than-ios_id121881 ?

Comment: In fact, what Cellebrite can do is covered by the wiki article on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellebrite_UFED and since an answer is found on wiki, and any answer will just be quoting public sources, I'll close this question and hope that the wiki link gives you the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer can be found on Wikipedia.

Comment: @schroeder The articles are very basic and don't really delve into the nitty gritty, but I got some more information for you if you'd like to try and surmise (they will probably never give the device back so all we can do is guess) about how they got it. He told me it was an S10 (base version) and when they arrested him it was not powered off, I think he had a fingerprint lock on. But they didn't try to gain access until over a month later. Do you think they kept the device powered on so they could get around the lock screen? His password is secure, we know that much.

Comment: If the password was so strong that they coudn't bruteforce it, the only option that they had was to keep it powered until they decrypt it with their exploits. Cellebrite recommends them to keep the device powered on.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not store lock screen credentials at all. [This is the cryptographic relationship between authentication of lock screen credentials and File Based Encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/247954/118310). File Based Encryption encrypts `/data` partition in android. This is what they mean with *full file disk encryption*. They still refer to the legacy and deprecated [Full Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/full-disk) term which is a predecessor of File Based Encryption. Breaking encryption of `/data` partition does not imply compromise of system partitions. System partitions are not encrypted. They don't have to be. They just have to be integrity protected. Android protects integrity of system partitions by enforcing [Android Verified Boot](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md#android-verified-boot-2_0) and [dm-verity](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot/dm-verity).

However, how the device encryption was broken could indicate that they are **capable** of compromising integrity of system partitions as well but they are not mutually inclusive. To break device encryption, what they need are attack vectors and entrypoints whose feasibility and availability depend on in which state the phone was in when it was seized.

If it was in **After First Unlock State**, they can:

1. Bypass lock screen using privilege escalation.
2. Compromise kernel to request decryption of data and have it exfiltrated from the device.
3. Compromise Trusted Execution Environment to decrypt File Based Encryption keys.

If it was in **Before First Unlock State**, they have to compromise Trusted Execution Environment to bypass cooldown timer in order to brute force lock screen credentials. There is no other way to get around it. However, your phone is less likely to be in Before First Unlock state unless it was shut down either by you or by the adversary or if its battery died.

None of the attack vectors mentioned above are practically feasible **by design**. No known vulnerabilities will work on a fully updated device. So, spyware agencies research on crafting critical severity exploits that use 0-day vulnerabilities for specific device models and they should at least work through charging port as an entrypoint which is what Cellebrite is doing.